# Chord of parabola which touches a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

The chord of the parabola $y = -a^2x^2 + 5ax - 4$ touches the curve
 $y =\frac1{1- x}$ at the point $x = 2$ and is bisected by that point. We have to find $a$.

I found the equation of line that is $x+y-1=0$

But how to proceed

Comment: What curve is that? It looks weird: (1)(1-x) ...what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry I have edited it @DonAntonio

Comment: I tried to fix your LaTeX notation. Please verify if the current version correctly reflects your problem description.

Comment: @user123733 When you write "touches the curve...", do you mean it is *tangent to it*, or merely *intersects it*?

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean tangent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint...you already have the correct tangent equation, so solve this simultaneously with the parabola, so that the points of intersection of the tangent and the parabola will satisfy the quadratic equation $$a^2x^2-x(1+5a)+5=0$$

You can then use "sum of roots $=-\frac ba$" to get an equation for $a$, since you know the midpoint is $2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- If at $x=2$ the curve is touched by the chord, find the tangent to curve at $x=2$, you'll get the chord
- Now a chord is bisected at $(x_1,y_1)$ then equation of that will be $(y+y_1)/2+a^2xx_1-5a(x+x_1)/2=y+a^2x^2-5ax$

Comment: Sorry , but I have edited the question